# Android notification opens multiple times instead of only once

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to show a notification when a  child is added into my Firebase Realtime Database. That notification must open only when the child added matches with the current user key.

It's shows normally when the child is added but every time I open the app (On Create method) it's shows again and again. In somehow that's indeed good. 
But also, it's shows every time the app is killed or when another child is added, even if the user key  it's not the current user.

Also,  sometimes,  when the notification opens it repeats 2 or 3 times at the same time.

Here's the code of the service

```
public class ListenTheOrderAgain extends Service {

    //Firebase
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference orders;
    Query query;

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    String currenNego;
    DatabaseReference socioReff;

    private String negocioOn, off;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = auth.getCurrentUser();

        if(user == null){


        } else {

            currenNego = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            socioReff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Shippers").child(currenNego);

        }


        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        orders = db.getReference("Solicitudes");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if(user == null){


        } else {

            socioReff.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("is_working"))){

                        query = orders.orderByChild("shipper").equalTo(currenNego);

                        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                                //Trigger here

                                PedidoModel result = dataSnapshot.getValue(PedidoModel.class);

                                if (result.getShipper().equals(currenNego)) {

                                    showNotification8(dataSnapshot.getKey(), result);
                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                        ///end

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }



    public ListenTheOrderAgain() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }



    public void showNotification8(String key, PedidoModel request) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent , 0);

        int notificationId = 1;
        String channelId = "channel-01";
        String channelName = "Channel Name";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId, channelName, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId)
                    .setTicker("Test Order")
                    .setContentInfo("New Order")
                    .setContentText("Hello, you have a new Order #" + key)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent);


            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());



        } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O){


            Intent intents = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntents = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent , 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builders = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());

            builders.setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setTicker("Test Order")
                    .setContentInfo("New Order")
                    .setContentText("Hello you have a new ORder #" + key)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntents)
                    .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500);



            NotificationManager managers = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            //IF YOU WANT TO MANY NOTFICATION SHOW, YOU NEED GIVE UNIQUE ID OFR ECHA NOTIFICAICION

            int randomInt = new Random().nextInt(9999-1)+1;
            managers.notify(randomInt, builders.build());

        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I call the service from the Main activity:

```
    //Call service
    Intent service = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListenTheOrderAgain.class);
    startService(service);
```

Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to create a FirebaseMessagingService:

In Manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".ListenTheOrderAgain"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

In your Service:

```
public class ListenTheOrderAgain extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

//your code for reading notifications
}
```

And you do not have to call startService. This service works without it.